# Unable to resolve module [external url] within the project or in these directories: node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, require

Im doing a project in react native

I have an object of exercises that include images and videos, everything is fine when the object was created, but when I imported into another file I get this error

undefined Unable to resolve module https://assets.soysuper.fit/cutted+mvp+mp4s/bodyweight_squats.mp4 from /mnt/c/Users/USER/Documents/superfit/app/src/screens/Patient/Workouts/ExercisesList.ts: https://assets.soysuper.fit/cutted+mvp+mp4s/bodyweight_squats.mp4 could not be found within the project or in these directories:  node_modules

[image]

This is the file of the exercises

[image]

And this is the file where I import it, when it happens, the apps automatically crashes with the error message

[image]

It would be awesome if someone wcould help me!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `require()` for URL, you only need it if the image/video/file is on your local machine.

so what you need is:

```js
export const exercises = {
  bodyWeightSquats: {
    ...,
    video: " https://assets.soysuper.fit/cutted+mvp+mp4s/bodyweight_squats.mp4 ",
    image: "https://yourlinktotheimage.com/something.png",
  }
```

Comment: That worked man! Thanks, but did you know why?

Comment: @SvenBrodersen Hi, glad to hear that it works! The reason is exactly as I wrote in the first sentence, there's no need to use `require()` for URL, you only need it for local files